# Gwt project fatal error in local using jetty

Tags: gwt, jetty

When I try to access a specific frame of my project, the jetty server on local crash with this error :

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5570ac2be8, pid=19458, tid=0x00007f54d81be700

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0x4b9be8]

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 An error report file with more information is saved as: /home/florian/git/gc-ui-sbe-pologne/target/gc-ui-sbe-pologne/hs_err_pid19458.log
```

The log file is [here](https://pastebin.com/gfc6ryuf)

The crash happen when the constructor of my class FrameRepairImei is called, and FrameRepairImei extends some classes that extends the Composite class. I put some breakpoints trying to locate the error, but I didn't even make to the first line of the constructor.

Here's the code for FrameRepairImei :

```
package com.example.com;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiTemplate;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.sbe.globalcare.client.GcUI;
import com.sbe.globalcare.client.views.frames.services.aftersale.repair.base.BaseFrameRepairImei;

public class FrameRepairImei extends BaseFrameRepairImei {

    private static BaseFrameRepairImeiUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(BaseFrameRepairImeiUiBinder.class);

    @UiTemplate("base/BaseFrameRepairImei.ui.xml")
    interface BaseFrameRepairImeiUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, FrameRepairImei> {
    }

    public FrameRepairImei(final GcUI project) {
        super(project);
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        initView();
    }

}
```

I'm a beginner at gwt so I coulnd find what cause the crash.
I find it weird that it only crashes on local, it never crashes when deployed on a tomcat.

Comment: Anything interesting in `BaseGcUI.goToRepairImeiFrame()`? According to the log file, that is what is actually calling the failing code in the JVM. Also, it looks like you are using legacy dev mode, which can't be supported in modern browsers (and isn't well tested in modern JVMs either) - this is why it doesn't happen when deployed in tomcat, since that will be a production build.

Comment: Here's the code for BaseGcUI.goToRepairImeiFrame() :                          
`public void goToRepairImeiFrame() {
   final FrameRepairImei frameRepairImei = new FrameRepairImei(getProject());

   // frameRepairImei.loadListManufacturer();
   gcMain.showFrame(frameRepairImei);

  }
  Window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 }` It craches at the creation of FrameRepairImei before the showFrame is called